# error: invalid operands to binary *

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
int main ()
{
  char buf[] ="14:15:43";
  int i;
  char *p;
  int *array[3];
  i = 0;
   p = strtok (buf,":");  
  while (p != NULL)
  {
   array[i++] = p;
    p = strtok (NULL, ":");
  }
  for (i=0;i<3; ++i) {
    //printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    array[i] = array[i] * 2;
 } 
return 0;
}
```

When I compile the above code I get this error:

```
split.c: In function ‘main’:
split.c:16:16: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
     array[i++] = p;
                ^
split.c:21:25: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘int *’ and ‘int’)
     array[i] = array[i] * 2;
                         ^
```

Comment: What exactly is `array[i] = array[i] * 2;` trying to accomplish?

Comment: array[i] *2 to double the array

Comment: @dbush ...missing `atoi()` I believe....

Comment: Same comment as dbush...  what are you trying to accomplish.  If it is to multiply each number found between the `:` delimiter, then you should be converting the string you have identified with `strtok` to `int` then saving in your array.  `array[i++] = atoi(p);`

Comment: ty this was the right answer

Answer (score 4):

*Regarding the `error`*

In your code, `array[i]` is of type `int *`, which cannot be used as the operand of multiply operator.

To quote the standard, chapter §6.5.5 , *Multiplicative operators*

> Each of the operands shall have **arithmetic type.**

<sup>~~~~*see note*~~~~~</sup>

*Regarding the `warning`*

That said,

```
 array[i++] = p;
```

looks very wrong. `array[n]` is of type `int *`, and `p` is of type `char *` and they are not compatible types. You may want to check your logic all over again.

**Solution**

It looks like, you want to perform arithmetic operation on the *numeric* value of the *string* content.  FYI, just casting the `char *` to `int *` does not make the content of the string to *appear* as `int`.

For that, you need to convert the string to arithmatic type first, say `int` or `long`. [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) may be of your help.

---

[NOTE]

*arithmetic type:*

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.2.5,

> Integer and floating types are collectively called arithmetic types.

Comment: changed it to char and getting this error split.c: In function ‘main’:
split.c:21:25: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘char *’ and ‘int’)
     array[i] = array[i] * 2;

Comment: split.c: In function ‘main’:
split.c:16:16: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
     array[i++] = p;

Answer (score 2):

A few errors here:

You're defining your array as `int *array[3]` i.e. an array of `int *`, however what you probably want is `int array[3]`, i.e. an array of `int`.

Next, as was mentioned elsewhere, `array[i++] = p` is invalid because you're trying to assign a `char *` to an `int *` (or an `int` if you first apply the first fix), which is invalid.  You want to convert the string to an integer using `atoi` as `array[i++] = atoi(p)`.

Lastly, your commented out `printf` in the `for` loop should be using `%d` for the format specifier instead of `%s`, since the array contains `int`.  You probably also want to move it down one line, right after `array[i] = array[i] * 2`.

With the above changes, you now have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
int main ()
{
  char buf[] ="14:15:43";
  int i;
  char *p;
  int array[3];
  i = 0;
   p = strtok (buf,":");
  while (p != NULL)
  {
   array[i++] = atoi(p);
    p = strtok (NULL, ":");
  }
  for (i=0;i<3; ++i) {
    array[i] = array[i] * 2;
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
 }
return 0;
}
```

Which outputs this:

```
28
30
86
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also mean something completely different.  Think about the meaning of "invalid operand".  I was getting it on

```
fftout[lochead][i][0] * fftout[lochead][i][0]
```

When I forgot the [i] terms.  I have 10 buffers, each with 4096 elements, each of those with 2 elements.  I didn't have enough indexes.

And yes, I'm just squaring the number.  It's part of a square root of sums of squares demodulation step.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a semicolon and got this same error because the compiler thought it was a multiply not a pointer dereference.

I had something like this:

```c
void **ptr = foo;

m->ptr = (void*)(m+1) // missing ;
*ptr = m->ptr;
```

Oops! The line needs a semicolon because the wrap thought the next line was a multiply!